# getAtrribute() returns null?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am not sure what is going wrong here but when i try to run my code, the wishlist.getAttribute returns null, yet if i specifically call with getElementById it will return the value i need. Though i need the wishlist.getAttribute to return the value as i am generating a link for each item in the wishlist and i need it to hold the product id.

*NOTE I do use a class instead of an Id in the  element for multiple links, though i have used an Id instead here to show that if i specifially call the element Id it will return the 'data-wish' attribute value.

### EDIT

`wishlist.getAttribute("data-wish");` returns null (wrong)
`document.getElementById("remove_wishlist").getAttribute("data-wish");` returns `2` (**the value I need**)

```
while ($rst = $query->fetch_assoc()){

    //... display wishlist product and remove item link

    echo '<a href="#" onclick="removeWishlist(wishlist);" id="remove_wishlist" data-wish="<?php echo $id; ?>"><strong style='color:rgba(255,0,0,0.8);'>Remove Item</strong></a>';
}
```

JS

```
function removeWishlist(wishlist){

    var $x = wishlist.getAttribute("data-wish");   //returns null when the link is clicked

    var $y = document.getElementById("remove_wishlist").getAttribute("data-wish");  //returns "2" (product id) 

    $(document).ready(function(){

        //remove selected item and reload wishlist
        $.ajax({
            url: "php/panel.php",
            data: { wishlist_id_remove: $x },
            type: "post",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            },

        });
    });
}
```

Just to add too, the PHP page where the wishlist items and remove item link are written is loaded into an element with Jquery.load() so i can automatically update the wishlist without refreshing the page, maybe this is contributing to my problem?

Comment: Please show the HTML markup of your page, not the PHP code you've used to generate it.

Comment: Where do you define `wishlist` for your `onclick` event? That is, what value is being passed to `removeWishlist()`?

Comment: @showdev the value being passed is the product id stored with the users wishlist items in the database. i query the DB and assign the value to $id

Comment: Bergi the <a> link is generated with php

Comment: If the var wishlist contains an id you have to query using this id like $('#' + wishlist).getAttribute("data-wish")

Comment: @diegorp i can't access it with an Id as i am usually using a class as it generates multiple links based on how many items are in the users wishlist, so i need to access it with wishlist.GetAttribute. I have used this else where on my site and it works fine, but for some reason it wont return the value if the page is loaded with jquery.load()

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your previous comment, your wishlist argument has to be the html element that contains the attribute you want to remove from your database. Can you show us the html? You probably has to change in your php onclick="removeWishlist(wishlist);" for onclick="removeWishlist(this);"

Comment: "You probably has to change in your php onclick="removeWishlist(wishlist);" for onclick="removeWishlist(this);" thank you, this was the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `this` as argument for the function called with `onclick`.

```
onclick="removeWishlist(this);"
```

Answer (score 5):

In adding to CoursesWeb's answer, this line

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="removeWishlist(wishlist);" id="remove_wishlist" data-wish="<?php echo $id; ?>"><strong style='color:rgba(255,0,0,0.8);'>Remove Item</strong></a>';
```

is wrong, if this code is already being ran from php it won't echo the value $id in `data-wish` attr. It will just output the string literal.

That line should be:

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="removeWishlist(this);" id="remove_wishlist" data-wish="'.$id.'"><strong style='color:rgba(255,0,0,0.8);'>Remove Item</strong></a>';`
```

Comment: @Liam I know, but in the other answer they tell him that. And this was too important and large as to put it in a comment.

Comment: Yes, fair enough. I'd reference CoursesWeb's answer too and say he needs both

Comment: yup onclick="removeWishlist(this);" was the issue, thank you very much. I had to give old mate the tick of approval as he initially answered correctly, though i do very much appreciate your additional info!